# alternative to Vlookup with VBA. compairing values from a column and copying the corresponding values from a second column to another column

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a task and I don't want to use `vlookup` because it makes the process very slow. I'm looking for a purely VBA code solution for the task.

Here I combine the values in column A and D in sheet 2. If the values in column A and B of sheet 1 are the same as that in sheet 2, then I copy the corresponding values in column G in sheet 2 to column D in sheet 1.

```
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Sending List").Select

    Dim Lastrow1, Lastrow2 As Long
    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim tempVal, tempVal2 As String

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sending List")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("P13 D-Chain Status")

    Lastrow1 = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrow2 = ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws2
        .Range("Q2:Q" & Lastrow2).Formula = "=A2&D2"
        .Range("R2:R" & Lastrow2).Formula = "=G2"
    End With

    With ws1
        .Range("D2:D" & Lastrow1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2&B2,'P13 D-Chain Status'!Q:R,2,0)"
    End With



  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The top of the procedure seems to be missing.. Consider setting `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual` while you drop formulas into worksheet cells; they'll only recalculate when you flip it back to `xlCalculationAutomatic`. Other than that, ...do you really need the formulas, or just their return values? If the former, see what [`Application.WorksheetFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) can do for you :)

Comment: Did you know `Lastrow1` `ws1` and `tempVal` are all `variants`!?

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon i dont need the formulas but thats the only method i could come out with

Comment: I don't know if you will be able to come up with anything faster than a built in formula.  The worksheetFunction suggestion is a good one, if you just want the values.  If you are having trouble with calculation times, then temporarily suspending calculation is a good suggestion.  Also, you might try using INDEX + MATCH instead of VLOOKUP.  Depending on the data you're using, INDEX/MATCH will be somewhere between 3 and 30% faster, and almost certainly not slower.  Alternatively, depending on your data, you might be able to use RANGE.FIND, but I doubt that's going to be faster than INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

=INDEX('P13 D-Chain Status'!Q:R,MATCH(A2&B2,'P13 D-Chain Status'!Q:Q,0),2)

But I don´t think it will work much faster.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This uses array instead of formulas.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet
    Dim wsO As Worksheet

    Dim wsIAr As Variant
    Dim wsOAr As Variant
    Dim FinaAr As Variant

    Set wsI = Sheet1 'Sheets("P13 D-Chain Status")
    Set wsO = Sheet2 'Sheets("Sending List")

    Dim lRowI As Long
    Dim lRowO As Long

    With wsI
        lRowI = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        wsIAr = .Range("A2:G" & lRowI).Value
    End With

    With wsO
        lRowO = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        wsOAr = .Range("A2:B" & lRowO).Value
    End With

    ReDim FinaAr(lRowO)
    Dim searchValue As String

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    For i = LBound(wsOAr) To UBound(wsOAr)
        searchValue = wsOAr(i, 1) & wsOAr(i, 2)
        For j = LBound(wsIAr) To UBound(wsIAr)
            If searchValue = wsIAr(j, 1) & wsIAr(j, 4) Then
                FinaAr(k) = wsIAr(j, 7)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        k = k + 1
    Next i

    wsO.Range("D2").Resize(lRowO, 1).Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FinaAr)
End Sub
```

Comment: wsO.Range("D2").Resize(lRowO, 1).Value = _                       what should be after the equal sign?

Comment: `_ ` is a line break. You can replace it with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(FinaAr)` or copy it to a new line as shown above

Comment: thanks alot, it work perfectly but still takes a long time to load

Comment: Sheets("P13 D-Chain Status") has 39000 and Sheets("Sending List") has 31000

Comment: any idea how to make that faster?

Comment: i can try. Can you tell me how much time Vlookup takes on your data and how much time does this code take on the data? Also Can I get the file that you have so that I can test on it?

Comment: i think this code is faster than the vlookup but still take time (around 4mins 35sec). the vlookup surely takes longer.

Comment: Can I get the file that you have so that I can do some tests on it?

Comment: how can i send it to you?

Comment: you can upload it to any file sharing site and post the link here. you can use one drive, dropbox, http://wikisend.com/ etc

Comment: hmmm, seems like i cant send the file to an external network